# Why are some disks and some are LUNs?

Tags: hardware, storage, solaris, zfs, sunos

Question at the bottom.

I would like to use a Sun StorageTek 6100 as JBOD for ZFS, and so I have connected it to OmniOS over FC with a QLC2462 HBA. The disk array doesn't have a controller tray, just an expansion tray, so no raid controller.

Both ports on the HBA are connected to the disk array in port 1B, so I am going for multiplexing. For one of the links I get errors on all the disks, where the other link is perfect.

```
# fcinfo remote-port -sl -p 210000e08b89bd75
Remote Port WWN: 200100a0b84f89cf
        Active FC4 Types: 
        SCSI Target: yes
        Port Symbolic Name: 
        Node WWN: 200000a0b84f89cf
        Link Error Statistics:
                Link Failure Count: 0
                Loss of Sync Count: 5
                Loss of Signal Count: 8
                Primitive Seq Protocol Error Count: 0
                Invalid Tx Word Count: 76
                Invalid CRC Count: 0
        LUN: 0
          Vendor: ATA     
          Product: HITACHI HUA7210S
          OS Device Name: /dev/rdsk/c3t200000A0B84F89CFd0s2
 ...
```

I have tried to replace the fibre, but the errors persist, and don't increase.

When looking at `format` I see 4 of the disks as expected, and not the remaining 10.

```
 ...
     /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000c5006443582b
 36. c3t200000A0B84EC566d0 <ATA-HITACHIHUA7210S-0609 cyl 60798 alt 2 hd 255 sec 126>
     /scsi_vhci/disk@g200000a0b84ec566
 37. c3t200000A0B84F2D06d0 <ATA-HITACHI HUA7210S-0609-931.51GB>
     /scsi_vhci/disk@g200000a0b84f2d06
 ...
```

`cfgadm -al` shows all 14 disks for both links.

**Question**

When there is no controller tray in the disk array, why am I not seeing all the disks?

Can the link error have something to do with this? If, how can it be fixed or reset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tx errors is either because of faulty fibers or HBA.

I am guessing you were using hardware raid before, right? And had 4 pools?

What you are seeing are not LUNs, but raw disks. Just use `zpool create` on the devices, and if the disks contain old pools, the you have to clear the beginning and end of the disk to get rid of that meta info.